# how to Show Heads-up notification when app is closed

Tags: android, kotlin, service, show, notify

I have used Service to get headsup notification from io.socket connections in my android kotlin project. Notification working if app is open. But, its not working when the app  is closed.  What should i add or change to get notification works in my project. please help me anyone...

Comment: This is what push messaging and FCM are for.

Comment: Thanks for your reply........... FCM consists of  limited usage in free tier only.... Is possible using foreground service or with broadcast receivers in it????

Comment: Foreground services don't last forever.  It will work better than a background service, but not completely.  The reality is that you're going to be paying either way-  if you have a socket listening for IO to come down you're paying for the server you're connected to.  Here you're paying for FCM.  If your app can't make enough revenue to afford it, your app isn't going to be a  viable business anyway

Comment: Thanks alot for your answers.... its very helpful for me...